# Generalization of $G/T \simeq G_\mathbb{C}/B$

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and Let $G_\mathbb{C}$ be its complexification. Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$ and let $X$ be the quotient $G/T$.

Consider $H$ to be a Lie subgroup of $G$ and denote by $H_\mathbb{C}$ its complexification. Let $x \in X$, denote by $H_x$ and ${(H_{\mathbb{C}})}_x$  the stabilizers of $x$ in $H$ and in $H_\mathbb{C}$ respectively.

Question : is $H/H_x$ isomorphic to $H_\mathbb{C}/{(H_{\mathbb{C}})}_x$?

Comment: I am [sorry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433928/generalization-of-g-t-simeq-g-mathbbc-b/433930#comment1117537_433928); I have deleted both my comment, and my answer, because I misread.  I thought that you had just changed the name of the group from $G$ to $H$, and didn't realise that you were taking $H$ to be a subgroup of $G$. \\ I can never remember the conventions.  Does "Lie subgroup" mean "immersed subgroup", "embedded subgroup", "closed subgroup", or something else?

Comment: For me $H$ is a closed Lie subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take $G = SU(2)$, $G_{\mathbb C} = SL_2(\mathbb C)$,  $G/B$ the complex projective line alias the sphere, $H$ the diagonal $U(1)$, $x$ any point other than the two fixed points of $H$, so that the orbit $H/H_x$ is a circular slice of the sphere, and $H_{\mathbb C}$ the diagonal $GL_1(\mathbb C)$, so that the orbit $H_{\mathbb C}/ (H_{\mathbb C})_x$ is the whole sphere minus two points.

The circle is not isomorphic to the whole sphere minus two points.